# Simple Form button collection does not save the field - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an input form in a RoR app built with simple_form.

One of the input fields is the category of the post, implemented as a collection of radio buttons. When saving the input, this field is empty and not saved. I cannot find why.

My form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |form| %>
<%= form.collection_radio_buttons(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name %>
<% end %>
```

My model:

```
 def new
    @post= Post.new
    @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
  end

def create
    @post = Post.new(params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description))
    @post.category_id = params[:category_id]
    @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
...
...
end
```

It is strange that everything works OK if I do it with a selectable drop-list instead:

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |form| %>
<%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories, selected: @post.category_id)) %>
<% end %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that in the first example (radio buttons), you're submitting your parameters as:

```
params = {
  post: {
    category_id: 1
  }
}
```

Whereas in the second example (select), you're submitting your parameters as:

```
params = {
  category_id: 1
}
```

This is because your first example creates the radio tag off of the form object (i.e. `form.collection_radio_buttons`) and the second example creates the select tag on its own ( i.e. `select_tag` as opposed to `form.select_tag` )

I would recommend updating your create action as follows and leaving your form.collection_radio_buttons as is:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :category_id))
  # @post.category_id = params[:category_id] # remove this line
  ...
end
```

This basically results in a simpler, more conventional form / controller setup that you'll see in examples all over the internet.